# SELECT statement to retrieve what never happened

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have CallHistory table with these columns:

```
CustomerId, TimeOfCall, CallResult
```

and in CallResult I may have values like:
'Placed Order', 'Requested Return', 'Technical Question', 'Inquired about Pricing', etc.

I want to `SELECT CustomerId FROM CallHistory WHERE` the customer has at least once 'Inquired about Pricing' but has never 'Placed Order'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it with a single select without joins or subqueries

Try this:

```
SELECT CustomerId
FROM CallHistory
GROUP BY CustomerId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN CallResult='Inquired about Pricing' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN CallResult='Placed Order' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really love this solution. Very elegant, and can be easily modified to "inquiried twice about pricing", and others.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.CustomerId
    FROM CallHistory c
    WHERE c.CallResult = 'inquired about Pricing'
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                           FROM CallHistory c2
                           WHERE c2.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                               AND c2.CallResult = 'Placed Order')
```

Comment: @Amarundo: Glad to help. Please remember to accept the answer you felt was best by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I didn't know that about checking the best answer. All answers are great. It's hard to choose one. I'll have to choose the one that is easier for me, not necessarily the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerId
  FROM CallHistory
 WHERE CallResult = 'Inquired about Pricing'
EXCEPT
SELECT CustomerId
  FROM CallHistory
 WHERE CallResult = 'Placed Order';
```